# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IMAGENS'

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm developing a project in python using pyqt5 and I need to import the images that are in another folder in the virtual environment but I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Projeto Controle de Estoque\TEMPLATES\tela_login.py", line 284, in <module>
    import IMAGENS.imagen_rc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IMAGENS'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmkTJ.png)

example:

testesVSCODE\main.py

```
from matematica.soma import somando

a = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
b = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
somando(a,b)
```

testesVSCODE\matematica\soma.py

```
def somando(a,b):
    return a + b
```

Comment: That probably means that the *working* directory is not the same that has the `IMAGENS` folder (assuming that the `imagen_rc.py` file *is* in a directory named `IMAGENS`). Try to change to `import .IMAGENS.imagen_rc`, if it works, remember to use the `--from-imports` flag of `pyuic`.

Comment: Create a minimal reproducible example to demonstrate the problem (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The root of your project needs to be on the Python path for Python to find the module there.